# Accidentally sent ETC to an ETH address

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic, poloniex

I incorrectly sent some ETC from my bter account to an ETH address on Poloniex.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa257d73760c8918aac1367ee983c1b4341f6c357

https://minergate.com/blockchain/etc/transaction/0x7a89c339c16b18536465a45554cbb55ccd9c76af16a73f64001dff11a6553149

After waiting for a couple of months on a response they told me: "I'm sorry, your ETH deposit address is blockchain specific so ETC can not be recovered from it."

Is there still anything I can do, or are the coins really lost forever?

What is a blockchain specific deposit address anyways?

edit:

Thanks for the responses. I mentioned the private key, but they specifically replied with the fact that my ETH address is "blockchain specific". What does that mean?

edit2:

I keep getting a flag that the question has been asked before, but I see no mention of contracts in the one I'm referred to. How is it a duplicate question then?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. I'm aware of the answer linked above, but it does not explain any of my questions... Why is it marked as a duplicate?

Comment: "blockchain-specific address" isn't an official term, it's just their way of describing the same thing that the linked answer says.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Correct me if I'm wrong, but to my understanding what lungji describes is that either I or someone else should have a private key of the receiving (ETH) wallet, but Poloniex says that there is no private key to control the wallet to retrieve the ETC. My question is, what kind of wallet am I dealing with then? Why is there no key as there would be in a "normal" wallet and why can't they retrieve ETC from it. What makes it "blockchain specific"? Sorry if I didn't phrase my question properly in the first place.

Comment: "No private key" means that the address is controlled by a contract. It's possible that there is no contract on the ETC chain, or there is a different contract on the ETC chain, or the same contract with different state. In that case, it's entirely possible that the funds got locked irrecoverably. I'm not familiar with ETC tools to investigate/debug further.

Comment: This question is old, however for some reason it was edited recently and brought back up. The deposit address `0xA257d73760c8918Aac1367ee983c1B4341F6C357` is a contract created by `0xb42b20ddbEabdC2a288Be7FF847fF94fB48d2579`. As contract addresses are deterministic, and Polinex hold the private key for the creator address, they **could** create a contract on ETC to allow them to withdraw and return your accidentally sent funds. However the nonce of the deposit contract is 14,560, which means they'd need to create the 14,559 prior contracts also. This would cost them a substantial amount.

Answer (score 2):

Gone forever most likely.  If you have the private key of the ETH address on Poloniex then it is the same on ETC, so you did send the ETC to that address on the ETC chain, you just don't have control.  Maybe poloniex will be nice if you ask them for the private key on that address, but I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: only poloniex can get this money. Because they own ETC address private which will be the same for ETH network.

Comment: Thanks, for the answers. I don't expect to get the coins back, but I just wanted to verify whether there really is nothing I can do about it. Seems like an easy way to lose a lot of coins on Poloniex. They did mention that I had a blockchain specific address when I mentioned the private key, and that nothing can be done because of this. But I don't understand what they mean by it...

Comment: Maybe poloniex uses some contract to hold the coins...I don't know.  But the addresses should be the same on both coins since the public key is mapped the same way from a private key.  My guess is they're just being lazy and the 'blockchain specific' excuse is just one to limit their liability in having to go search around for it.

Comment: The contract was created on May 27th of 2017, after the fork between both chains. So it doesn't exist in ETC, the creator account seems very active in ETH but not on ETC. I'd guess that is not easy to recreate the contract in ETC, but the biggest problem is perhaps poloniex infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Ismael. Also thanks again for your time thefett. This sounds like what they tried to tell me, but it seems strange to me that they have no control over anything other than ETH in their ETH wallets. I had hoped that at some point something could be done to get the coins back, but it already took 70+ days to get a single reply on my ticket. I don't think I'll get a response anymore from them, let alone that they will actually take the time to fix it. Could you maybe explain a bit what a contract is in this context?